# Открытие окна при всех input:checked

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть [3 checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ASPUA/):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Check all</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 3</label>
```

и скрипт:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.thing'),
    checkall = document.getElementById('checkall');

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
        var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.thing:checked').length;

        checkall.checked = checkedCount > 0;
        checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
    }
}

checkall.onclick = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
}
```

в css добавляем:

```
#checkall:checked{
  display:none;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе трех *checkbox*, срабатывало css свойство ?

Comment: вы имеете в виду, что вам надо скрыть label#checkall, когда все из чекбоксов имеют активное состояние?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.thing'),
    checkall = document.getElementById('checkall');

for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
        var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.thing:checked').length;
        checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
        if(checkedCount == checkboxes.length){
          checkall.checked = true;
        }else{
          checkall.checked = false;
        };
    }
}

checkall.onclick = function() {
    for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
}
```

```css
#checkall:checked {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Check all</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="thing"> Thing 3</label>
```